# How to make ultrasound audible?

Tags: audio, ultrasound

Because of interesting spectral phenomena, I would like to shift the >20kHz content of my audio recordings to audible frequencies, so that I can listen to it.
I tried the Audacity pitch correction feature, but didn't succeed.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't succeed"? Did it crash, nothing was audible or too much low-frequency noise?

Comment: Long time since I did this by just changing the sample rate of WAV file (HEX editor needed).

Comment: How did you collect these audio recordings? All audio equipment I've touched, even if it samples at 96 kHz, has analog anti-aliasing filters that cut off somewhere below 20 kHz.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: In my case https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?topic=106205.0

Comment: @JuhaP interesting, so what recording equipment did you use? W.H.G., what's your recording equipment?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I had Technics turntable with their own 205CMK3 cart ( response info : https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=106205.0;attach=7965 ), E-MU 0404USB ( http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/proaudio/emu-0404-usb.html ) as a recording device.

Comment: I used the digital recorder Tascam-DR05 at 96k sample rate and 16bit depth.

Comment: @jojek: Audacity crashed every time.

Comment: @W.H.G. if Audacity crashed, then there's not much we can do for you but point out that you should probably reporting that bug. Or, use a different software to shift your signal in frequency.

Comment: @W.H.G. I am more of a console guy. You can try to use sox with `pitch` effect. Something like: `sox in.wav -r44.1k out.wav pitch -2400`, which will shift the signal down by 24 semi-tones (2 octaves). So 40 kHz becomes 10 kHz, etc. Finally, it will save the output to 44.1k audio file. You might want to do some high-pass (or even band-pass) filtering on the output.

Comment: @jojek Thanks, I tried that but can't find the output file - should this end up in the sox directory? Any hint on that?

Comment: I will be in the current directory.

Comment: @jojek Thanks, but can't find it there. I'll see if I can set an alternative wdir.

Comment: @W.H.G. check if something simpler works, such as `sox in.wav -r44.1k out.wav`.

Comment: @jojek Thanks, the simpler command worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @jojek:

SoX:

```
sox in.wav -r44.1k out.wav
```

Comment: Can you explain what the -r44.1k implies?